# Dynamicreports: Remove black border wrapped legend

Tags: jfreechart, dynamic-reports

I am using dynamicreports4.1.1

When I draw barCharts, I want to **remove the black border wrapped the legend**,

**but not remove the total legend**.
[image]

I tried to customize the chart render but failed, I can't find what properties it use.

Comment: I found the setting, **chart.getLegend().setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);**, amazing, every time after I post, I can suddenly find answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

```
LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();

    //necessary when some set showLegend=false
    if(legend!=null){
        legend.setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);//去除legend的黑线框
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.